# How do I transfer my Google Chrome profile to a new PC?

Tags: google-chrome

Now that I have Google Chrome all set up, I got myself a new laptop. Does anyone have any idea how to transfer my settings, cookies, favorites, etc?

I checked `documents and settings\me\application data`, and found nothing.

Comment: I tried both ways, but my OLD PC settings of CHROME donot show up in new install on new laptop. OLD = WinXP
New = Win7. Used CMD> %APPDATA% to discover the hidden Path and all. I copied in RAR format and unzipped, to recreate the files like original. What am I missing ? Also tried to SYNC but there is no explicit SYNC-to-ACCOUNT-from-current-PC.
It seems you can only ENABLE and DISABLE a continuous SYNC process. How to SYNC your PAST HISTORY/ Bookmarks etc. RIGHT NOW --- its not clear at all. Probly I erred -- signed in on new laptop first; but I shud hav signed in FIRST on OLD one. Now I have

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[This link](https://www.howtogeek.com/255653/how-to-find-your-chrome-profile-folder-on-windows-mac-and-linux/) should help you out - basically:

- On XP - C:\Documents and Settings&lt;User Name>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data
- On Vista - C:\Users&lt;User Name>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data

Comment: Warning: While this generally works, you will lose all stored passwords since they are encrypted using a Windows API that uses a machine/account specific key, which obviously will be different on any other machine/account.

Comment: @ThiefMaster but in chrome://settings/passwords you can hit those three vertical dots and choose Export Passwords as a way to migrate passwords.

Comment: @AndrewHarvey not anymore.

Comment: This answer is now less helpful because of a broken link.

Answer (score 19):

1. While logged in to the profile you wish to migrate (normally named `Default` if you didn't add additional profiles) enter the following URL in the address bar:

   **`chrome://version`**
2. Copy the path listed under **Profile Path**
3. Shut down chrome and then zip the folder and transfer it to the same location on the other machine.

> *Exclude the **Cache** folder under your profile folder to reduce file size. For example, you can copy  the profile folder to a temporary location, delete the `Cache` sub-folder and then zip it.*

If you have more profiles then repeat the operation while logged into each profile.

Comment: Show `chrome://version` on **each profile**.

Answer (score 13):

On your old computer:

- Go to Google Chrome, and then type in the address bar: `chrome://settings/personal` (or just navigate to Settings).
- Click "sync to my account" (or something like that) to sync it to your Google account.

On your new computer:

- Click the wrench icon.
- Click sign in to Chrome.

As soon as you sign in to your synced Google account, all of your settings, bookmarks, etc. are transferred.

Answer (score 6):

You’ll find many sites showing you where the profile data is stored on disk, but moving the folders alone is insufficient. The secret ingredient is to bring over the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\PreferenceMACs registry key.

Here’s everything you need to do:

- On the computer that has the Chrome profiles that you want to retain:
  Copy the “User Data” folder found in this path to portable media: `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\`
- Export this registry key to the same portable media: `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\PreferenceMACs]`
- Move the portable media to your new computer.
- On the computer that you want to move the Chrome profiles to:
- Make sure all Chrome browser windows are closed and chrome.exe is not running
- Copy the “User Data” folder from your portable media to `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\`
- Double-click the registry key that you saved to portable media in step 2
- Open Chrome, and you’ll find your profiles are present!

Comment: Bless you, this did the trick for me. I'll note that when I only copied the specific Profile subfolders over, not the whole User Data, this did not seem to work.

Comment: I tried this with many `--user-data-dir` for transfer from Win10 to Win11 but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

```
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\RA.N.DO.M Numbers
```

copy this folder and replace only the contents inside the Random Numbered Folder this is where all of your contents are held.

```
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\23.0.1271.91
```

Click inside the folder and a list of files will be there this is what you need to copy and move over to another computer

When moving this file over to a new computer you must first install google chrome and establish a new profile number ( that's why the number is random )

delete the contents in the newly created profile and paste over the contents from the old profile.

Open chrome up and you are back in business.

#### Windows 7 to Windows 8 machine

If you wish to do a folder migration from XP to Windows 7 or 8 it is going to be

```
C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\RA.N.DOM Numbers
```

Comment: I tried editing this, but I cannot figure out what it is trying to say. Those “random numbers” are *not random*, they are the *version* of Chrome. After you update it a few times, you will have several folder where each one is named for the version of Chrome installed in it.     (For some reason, Google decided that it is a good idea to keep *every* version of Chrome you have ever used—my folder is currently >700MB.)

Answer (score 2):

You can to [override the User Data Directory](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md#overriding-the-user-data-directory). To check where is located, navigate to: `chrome://version`.

Or you can start Chrome with the existing User Data, e.g.

> Example:
>
> - [Windows] `chrome.exe --user-data-dir=c:\foo`
> - [Linux] `google-chrome --user-data-dir=/path/to/foo`

On Linux, you can also set `CHROME_USER_DATA_DIR` environment variable pointing to the user data directory.

Check also: [Where are the user profile directories of Google Chrome located in?](https://superuser.com/q/329112/87805)

Answer (score 0):

It does not work now, you will lose all stored passwords since they are encrypted using a Windows API that uses a machine/account specific key, which obviously will be different on any other machine/account. Browser Transfer application maybe useflul, https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9PP4M2NK8PC8.

They promise to transfer all as https://youtu.be/AWtpvXB5HsU