# Google Chrome; restore chrome user data

Tags: google-chrome

is it possible to restore Google chrome user data once the user profile has been deleted?
I accidentally deleted users and I need to restore my bookmarks.  I don't know where to begin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I transfer my Google Chrome profile to a new PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/367741/how-do-i-transfer-my-google-chrome-profile-to-a-new-pc)

Answer (score 1):

if you have synchronize your email then if you just add that account again then it will bring all the bookmarks in chrome.(ie. when you added your gmail account first time re add that account).

Answer (score 0):

You can to [override the User Data Directory](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md#overriding-the-user-data-directory). To check where is located, navigate to: `chrome://version`.

Or you can start Chrome with the existing User Data, e.g.

> Example:
>
> - [Windows] chrome.exe --user-data-dir=c:\foo
> - [Linux] google-chrome --user-data-dir=/path/to/foo

On Linux, you can also set `CHROME_USER_DATA_DIR` environment variable pointing to the user data directory.

Check also: [Where are the user profile directories of Google Chrome located in?](https://superuser.com/q/329112/87805)

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: I've marked it as duplicate, after I realized there is another similar post. Secondly, it's not clear, whether it's going to be duplicate.