# Explorer.exe Stops Responding Once Logged In

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

My sister came to me with a problem she's having with her laptop.

She's running Windows Vista and once you login explorer.exe stops responding and restarts. This continues and is not operable.

[**NOTE:** This is not just a Vista related problem.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2694911)

However the guest account works fine. I also made a new user `Hello` and it too works fine.

What I've tried...

- Drivers are all upto date, I used task manager to close all apps that may conflict with Windows explorer.
- I have several spare and new ram chips lying around. Thus I upgraded her RAM from 2GB to 4GB with new chips.
- I have a friend who lend me his "Windows Anytime Upgrade" CD. I backed up her data (Thanks to Linux) and ran System Restore.

Unfortunately the problem still persists.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Not to solve, but to test, create another fresh new user, make sure that works always, identify that works in your question here. Then assume there is some software running under the other user that causes problems. or some context menu items which have been known to cause that (among other things).

Comment: Is tested a new user account and it does not experience the problem.

Comment: Just migrate the old user account data to the new user account. Sounds like the old user profile is corrupt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explorer.exe repair:**

It might be there are some broken autostart scripts on user level. 
You can try to start Windows safe mode by **pressing F8 while booting**. Have a look if explorer.exe crashes in safe mode.

You can find some errors about application errors of the explorer in the event viewer.

Try to disable some 3rd party applications in **msconfig.exe** if explorer.exe works as normal in safe mode.

If you don't find the cause you can try **[Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)** from Microsoft Sysinternals. It has an Explorer part.

**Firefox bookmarks backup:**

There is a file called **[places.sqlite](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite)** which contains all the bookmarks in a Firefox profile folder. 
`"%APPDATA%\Mozilla\"`
Or longer:

```
C:\Users\insert_your_username_here\Appdata\Mozilla\Random_Number.default\places.sqlite
```

You can backup that file and create a new [Firefox Profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_Manager) and restore that file, if you still need that.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as the problem did not persist with a new user account what I did is I migrated her data to the new user account using Command Prompt. ([Backup Firefox Data](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/back-and-restore-information-firefox-profiles) and [Backup Google Chrome Data](https://superuser.com/questions/367741/how-do-i-transfer-my-google-chrome-profile-to-a-new-pc))