# Can I enable an extension synced via Google only on some Chrome installs?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Google Chrome's sync feature is quite nice and very useful in many instances, though a few are somewhat annoying.  Mouse Gesture extensions somewhat lose their usefulness and occasionally get in the way on laptops.

Whenever I enable or disable the extension on either of my computers, it syncs that with the other; can I selectively break this link somehow?

Comment: This is an answer: 
 http://superuser.com/questions/528014/how-to-disable-chrome-extensions-without-disabling-them-across-multiple-synced-d

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Chrome extensions without disabling them across multiple synced devices](https://superuser.com/questions/528014/how-to-disable-chrome-extensions-without-disabling-them-across-multiple-synced-d)

Answer (score 1):

Not my answer, content copied to avoid link rot from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/528014/how-to-disable-chrome-extensions-without-disabling-them-across-multiple-synced-d/531651#531651).

---

> Based on the security concern, Chrome doesn't sync any extension which contains an NPAPI plugin.

<sup>[Source](http://code.google.com/p/chrome-screen-capture/wiki/EnglishFAQ)</sup>

#### What is a NPAPI plugin?

> Code running in an NPAPI plugin has the full permissions of the current user and is not sandboxed or shielded from malicious input by Google Chrome in any way. You should be especially cautious when processing input from untrusted sources, such as when working with content scripts or XMLHttpRequest.

<sup>[Source](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html)</sup>

### Theory

If we modify your extension in a way that Chrome recognize the extension using NPAPI, you should be fine.

### How to

1. First, you neet a dummy .dll from any NPAPI extension like [Screen Capture by Google](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-capture-by-google/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg/related)
   Install the extension and search the file `screen_capture.dll` in Chrome's [user profile folder](https://superuser.com/questions/329112/where-are-the-user-profile-directories-of-google-chrome-located-in)
   `..\profile\Default\Extensions\cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg\5.0.5_0\plugin`
2. Second, go to the extensions folder that should not be synced. In your case *Gestures for Chrome*.
   `..\profile\Default\Extensions\jpkfjicglakibpenojifdiepckckakgk\1.12.1_0`
3. Modify the *manifest.json* file and add the NPAPI plugin as [described on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392536/developing-chrome-extensions-using-npapi-in-c)

   ```
   "plugins": [
       { "path": "your_npapi_plugin.dll" }    
   ],
   ```
4. Modify the *background.html* file, also described on the Stackoverflow answer above.

   ```
   <script>
   var plugin = document.getElementById("MyNPAPIPluginId");
   ...
   </script>
   ```

From here you are on your own.  I don't know enough about extensions coding.
Thats why it is a theory :)

Answer (score -2):

Under Settings->Advanced Sync Settings choose to not sync extensions.

An alternative would be to create a new Google account for laptops and add a new user to Chrome that uses the newly created account to sync from.

Comment: @viiron-Your first way will stop syncing all the extensions.Nick T wants to sync or not sync only specific extensions.