# Disable Chrome extensions at one location only

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I've got a laptop and home PC that I have Chrome installed on. There are some extensions that I want to be enabled on my laptop (since I use it more regularly), and disabled on my home computer. If I disable it on the PC, it's disabled on the laptop. Is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: this is possible only if there is some add on for this.

Comment: [This user](http://superuser.com/questions/528014/chrome-plugin-sync-across-multiple-devices-any-way-to-disable-a-plugin-on-a-par) doesn't want to disable sync globally nor use two profiles (maybe because of bookmarks & settings sync). With [some effort](http://superuser.com/a/531651/50173) you can manipulate that particular extension so it won't be synced. There is no easy way without disadvantages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have signed in to chrome. that's why syncing happens. So just use two different mail ids for sign in.

OR

go to `chrome->settings->advanced sync settings`.
default option will be sync everything. select 'choose what to sync' from drop down.
disable extensions and settings