# How to disable Chrome's extension sync, only the "enable" part?

Tags: google-chrome

I have multiple computers and for non-retina ones I use some extension that is not working well with retina ones. So I like to disable this extension on my retina computers, but enable them on non-retina ones. Chrome seems to sync the "enable" and "disable" - I want to disable this feature - but I want to keep the syncing, just not syncing enable or disable. Can this be done?

Comment: Check this: http://superuser.com/questions/528014/how-to-disable-chrome-extensions-without-disabling-them-across-multiple-synced-d/

Comment: @shub thank you so much! Do you know if I can do it on an OS X system? And do you know how?

Comment: I've added an answer - hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on windows, use [this](https://superuser.com/questions/528014/how-to-disable-chrome-extensions-without-disabling-them-across-multiple-synced-d/) (The answer from WORMSS should do)

If you are on Mac, go to `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions` by pressing <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> after pressing on the desktop or Finder. Go to the page of your extension (eg. [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/merge-windows/adjadgadeebehakpgamlnafmdkegkmph)) and copy the 'random' letters at the end (eg. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/merge-windows/**adjadgadeebehakpgamlnafmdkegkmph**). Now find that folder in the `Extensions` folder.(this is step 1).

Now, carry on with the link I mentioned at the beginning, it should work.

Of course, there is always the option to manually do everything but that could take some time. The first option will need repeating every update, but you could eventually make an applescript to automate this for you - although I do not know how to do that, I'm sure a quick Google should help. The other will have to be updated every time you want a new extension, it all depends on how much time you have and how many computers  /extensions you have.

Comment: "First, you neet a dummy .dll from any NPAPI extension" - for OS X , there is no .dll, what should I use as the "dummy .dll?"

Comment: @AeroWindwalker I was referring to answer no. 2 (from WORMSS), where you make the extension a local copy and disable the 'real' one. This is why I said it would be a bit time consuming. Sorry, I should have  made this more clear. Meanwhile, I will try to find out how to use the first users method (if there is a way)

Comment: thanks. Just FYI, disable is not enough, you must remove the original extension. This means manual installing the extension in all the machine and manual updating on each single one of them. But hey, it gets the work done.

Comment: @AeroWindwalker The only reason (AFAIK) that you should disable instead of remove is that it can be used as a backup. But if it doesn't work then you have to to that don't you? I recommend you keep some type of list of extensions you have - in case something horribly wrong happens