# signed in accounts folder location for google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, user-accounts, google-accounts

I recently had to reinstall windows on a different SSD which wiped all chrome settings. I was able to sync them back using my main account but I had other signed in accounts that are gone. I have access to the old %localappdata% google folder on the original drive but I can't seem to find a list of the emails/passwords anywhere. I tried to search through the login data in the default folder but the email addresses weren't there.
I already looked at C:\Users$username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data. but that only shows the login emails for sites I used what I am looking for is the list of gmail accounts that were signed into.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are the user profile directories of Google Chrome located in?](https://superuser.com/questions/329112/where-are-the-user-profile-directories-of-google-chrome-located-in)

Comment: Based on reinstalling Windows as you have done, you will probably need to contact Google support

Comment: https://www.askcybersecurity.com/where-are-my-saved-passwords-in-chrome/#FindChromeSavedPasswordsWindows Your Google Chrome password file is located on your computer at C:\Users\$username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default.